# Reverse Numeric Matrix by Row

Tags: c++, rcpp

Using `Rcpp`, for a package that I am writing in R, I am trying to reverse a NumericMatrix, so that the last row now would become the first, and the first row would become the last, in other words, the relative row indexes would go from `1, 2, 3, ... n` to `n, n-1, n-2, .... 1`

So, if I declare the following function:

```
NumericMatrix reverseByRow(NumericMatrix in){
  int r = in.nrow();
  NumericMatrix nw(r,in.ncol());
  for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
    nw.row(i) = in.row(r-i-1);
  }
  return nw;
}
```

And I have an 'N x M' Numeric matrix called 'mid', which I am trying to reverse by row, via the following:

```
        cout << "Reversing1: " << mid(0,0) << endl;
        cout << "Reversing2: "<< mid(1,0) << endl;
        mid = reverseByRow(mid); 
        cout << "Reversed1: " << mid(0,0) << endl;
        cout << "Reversed2: " << mid(1,0) << endl;
```

Why am I getting the following output, suggesting that nothing has changed...???

```
Reversing1: 2806
Reversing2: 7
Reversed1: 2806
Reversed2: 7
```

Surely I am missing something very obvious... ???

Comment: Are you sure this is not a coincidence? What does the whole `mid` look like?

Comment: When I tested your function (after changing the name of the parameter `in` to something that didn't cause a compilation error) on this object - `matrix(1:9, nrow=3)` - it worked correctly.

Comment: @nrussell beat me to it. Works here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a 'fixed' version with a suitable variable name:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix reverseByRow(NumericMatrix inmat) {
  int r = inmat.nrow();
  NumericMatrix nw(r,inmat.ncol());
  for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
    nw.row(i) = inmat.row(r-i-1);
  }
  return nw;
}

/*** R
M <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
M
reverseByRow(M)
*/
```

which works as expected:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/nicholas.cpp")

R> M <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)

R> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

R> reverseByRow(M)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    6    9
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    1    4    7
R>
```